# jboss - increase list of project deployed

Tags: java, deployment, jboss, web-deployment, web-deployment-project

I have list of project deployed on Jboss

[image]

When I deploy new project, It will be on next page.

It takes time for me when I need to enable/disable or redeploy

Is there any option to increase paging number ?

Thanks